# Ready-made Dynamics NAV 2009 web services for integration with e-commerce system?

Tags: web-services, e-commerce, dynamics-nav

I'm planning to integrate our e-commerce module with Navision. I know you can set up and configure web services in NAV 2009, but I'm not familiar with Navision, and would like a more out-of-the-box solution, that we can quickly set-up for other customers.

Does anyone here have experience with any ready-made web service solutions for NAV 2009?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a set of web services which will expose your NAV data to an already decided ecommerce platform or are you looking for a NAV add-on that *is* your ecommerce platform?

Taking into account your comment (looking for services to expose NAV data to your pre-existing ecommerce platform):

In my experience, this is one of those situations where there simply doesn't exist a really good off the shelf solution. Depending on the complexity of your NAV environment it should be relatively simple to build your own web services which will expose the data you need, in the format you need it, to your ecommerce platform.

Is your ecommerce platform bespoke or off the shelf? What sort of data are you looking to expose?

Comment: I'm looking for a set of web services which will expose the NAV data to our own ecommerce module.

Comment: Edited my answer to take this into account.